# Multiple archives to display parent and subcategories content

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy

I am developing a plugin with custom types and my problem is that I need to display an archive of a selected subcategory (selected from a parent category) and in the page display some events of that subcategory.

In my plugin I have:

```
if ($post->post_type == 'events') {
  if(is_single()) {
    .....
  } elseif(is_archive()) {
    $template_path = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/views/archive-events.php';
  }
}
```

In the archive-events.php, I have the parent categories.
When I click on one parent category, I have to go to another archive with the list of the subcategories from that parent and with another click on one subcategory I have to go to another archive page with all events from that subcategory.

In my archive-events.php I have this code:

```
<?php
    $terms = get_terms( 'event_category', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => true
) );

foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    // Check and see if the term is a top-level parent. If so, don't display it.
    $parent = $term->parent;
    if ( $parent!='0' ) {
        // Define the query
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'events',
            'event_category' => $term->slug
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        echo'<a href="'.home_url().'/big-events/'.$term->slug.'"><span class="cat-name">' . $term->name . '</a>';

    }

}           
?>
```

Actually my problem is that also if I click on a subcategory, the plugin redirects me in the same is_archive() page with the correct URL, but with all the other subcategories displayed.

Is there a way to define different is_archive() page based on the subcategory?
Any help is more than welcome!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below, you are grabbing terms from the event_category taxonomy
Note that you are always grabbing the same terms though.

```
$terms = get_terms( 
    'event_category', 
    array(
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => true
    )
);
```

If you want to grab only from the current pages children, then you should grab the current term and set your term list to only grab children of the current term:

```
$current_term = $wp_query->queried_object;
$terms = get_terms(
    'event_category',
    array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'parent' => $current_term->parent
    )
);
```

Here you are cycling through them...

```
foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    // Check and see if the term is a top-level parent. If so, don't display it.
    $parent = $term->parent;
    if ( $parent!='0' ) {

        // Define the query
```

What are you trying to do with this query?
You are creating it, but then doing nothing with it.

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'events',
            'event_category' => $term->slug
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This just writes out a link:

```
        echo'<a href="'.home_url().'/big-events/'.$term->slug.'"><span class="cat-name">' . $term->name . '</a>';
```

It might be better to do something like:

```
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($term) . '"><span class="cat-name">' . $term->name . '</span></a>';
    }

}           
?>
```

rewritten a bit:

```
<?php
$current_term = $wp_query->queried_object;
$children = get_terms(
    'event_category',
    array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'parent' => $current_term->parent
    )
);
if ( !is_wp_error( $children ) && is_array( $children ) && 0 < count( $children ) ) {
    foreach ( $children as $child_term ) {
        $child_link = get_permalink( $child_term );
        echo <<<HTML
<a href="{$child_link}"><span class="cat-name">{$child_term->name}</span></a>
HTML;

    }
} else {
    # No child terms were found
}
?>
```